# Handle different data models to display specific properties in tableView

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary, mapping

Considering these two objects :

```
struct Product {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let price: Int
    let categoryId: Int
}

struct Category {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

And these two object arrays :

```
let products = [
    Product(id: 1, title: "snake", price: 20, categoryId: 1),
    Product(id: 2, title: "soap", price: 20, categoryId: 2),
    Product(id: 3, title: "cream", price: 20, categoryId: 3),
    Product(id: 4, title: "dog", price: 20, categoryId: 1),
    Product(id: 5, title: "car", price: 20, categoryId: 4),
]

let categorieItems = [
    Category(id: 1, name: "animal"),
    Category(id: 2, name: "chemichal"),
    Category(id: 3, name: "food"),
    Category(id: 4, name: "travel"),
]
```

How can I handle these two structures to assign in the cellForRowAt indexPath tableView method the product title property to cell.textLabel?.text and the corresponding category name (linked with the categoryId property) contained in categorieItems to the cell.detailTextLabel?.text

For example :
cell.textLabel?.text = snake
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = animal

Comment: filter categorieItems to get exact category for that product ? will it work for you ?

Comment: write a function that takes category id and return category from categorieItems ...

Comment: `private func getCategoryForID(_ categoryId: Int) -> Category {
    categorieItems.filter { $0. id == categoryId }
}`

Comment: Exactly what is the problem, could you explain in more detail why you can't assign values to the labels in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function that takes category id and return category from categorieItems

like

```
 private func getCategoryForID(_ categoryId: Int) -> Category {
 categorieItems.filter { $0.id == categoryId }
 }
```